# How to call execl (or simlar) and set signal handlers for the child process?

Tags: c, signals, exec

I am trying to write a program, `caller`, which traps `SIGINT` with `sigaction`, and calls an external program, `prog`.
I understand how to use `sigaction` on a simple program, but I don't know how to use it to set signal handlers for other processes (called by `execl`, for example).

The following is a MWE:

`caller.c` is this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

void got_sig(int sig) {
    printf("SIGNAL caught: %d\n",sig);
}

int main () {
    struct sigaction sa;
    (void) sigfillset(&sa.sa_mask);
    sa.sa_handler = got_sig;
    sa.sa_flags=0;
    sigaction(SIGINT,&sa,NULL);
    printf("\n");
    execl("./prog", "./prog", (char*) NULL);
}
```

`prog.c` is this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main() {
    for(int i=0; ; i++) {
        sleep(1);
        printf("epoch: %d\n",i);
    }
}
```

But when I run `caller`, I see the output of `prog.c`, and hitting `^C` *does* stop the prorgam (the signal is  not trapped).
I suppose this is related to how  `execl` works (it creates a new process, which does not inherit the parents' signal handlers -- is this right?)
So, how can I accomplish what I am trying to do?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

```
execl("./prog", "./prog", "./prog", (char*) NULL);
```

Or if it's not working, check out here: https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/exec.html